# IE get visible width but not real width of the overflowed span

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have next code

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbead>
    <tr>
       <td id="container">
         <span id="innerText">Some long text here</span>
       </td>....
    </tr>....
  <tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
container{
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
max-width:100px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var $span = $("#innerText");
var $spanWidth = $span.width(); //I also tried $span[0].scrollWidth, innerWidth, outerWidth
var $containerWidth = $("#container").width();
if($containerWidth<$spanWidth)
{
   //Do things
}
```

So in Chrome it works like I want, it return true width of span element and detect that it is not fit container. But in IE what ever I try it returning visible width of span, so it always smaller then container. Do someone have any suggestion?

Thanks.

*Addition*

The id's is not quite important, because I using jquery to select all . So column inner text ("very long text here") would be visible as "very lo...". But I need to know length of that "very long text here" and if I use .width() in Chrome it working, but in IE it give me length of "very lo...".

Comment: For now I created a workaround: Copy span content to hidden div and compare that div and container width. It still not perfect as have some +/-20 px gap for different browsers. But it is best solution what I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#innerText{display:inline-block}

var l=(container.offsetWidth-innerText.offsetLeft);
```

Comment: Sorry, that one didn't worked. I thought that it not important to say that this is all inside table, but looks like it is also some key thing. So I updated my question. The id's is not quite important, because I using jquery to select all <td>. So column inner text ("very long text here") would be visible as "very lo...". But I need to know length of that "very long text here" and if I use .width() in Chrome it working, but in IE it give me length of "very lo...".